# What is available during Apple Developer site outage?

Tags: ios, macos

I have a free Apple Developer account. I am about to upgrade to a paid account so I can download XCode 5 and iOS 7 SDK. Can someone with a paid account tell me whether these downloads are available during the current outage?

Comment: Better question: what the hell *happened*?

Comment: This is really more of an Apple support question that's not related to programming.

Answer (score 3):

Apple opened [System Status](https://developer.apple.com/support/system-status/) site. But downloads are not available yet.

Comment: Additionally, I don’t think you can even upgrade your account while the dev center is down, can you?

Comment: Yeah, anyone wanting to upgrade should wait.

Answer (score 2):

Now apple site under maintenance, you need to wait until Resource Center is LIVE:

https://developer.apple.com/support/system-status/